# Java - how to parse yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ to a specific time zone and format?

Tags: java, parsing, time

how to parse yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ into my specific timezone and only display the time?

For example:
from 2017-11-22T22:00:00Z
to 2017-11-22 23:00

Because my timezone is one hour ahead of the timezone that the first string was from, I hope you understand!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27340650/how-to-convert-a-instant-to-a-localtime

Comment: Your use of the year `0001` raises calendar issues connected to year zero, and trying to represent historic dates. If your actual Question is about contemporary times, edit to show that.

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting. Issues of parsing an ISO 8601 string, adjusting into a time zone, and extracting a time-of-day have all been handled many times already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, parse your string as an `Instant`, then convert that to a `ZoneDateTime` in the desired zone; from that, you can obtain the `LocalTime`

```
LocalTime time = Instant.parse(str).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalTime();
```

Answer (score 4):

If using Java 8, you can parse it as an `Instant` and then convert it to a `ZonedDateTime` in the time zone you need. You can then get the local time from the `ZonedDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse("2017-11-22T22:00:00Z");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
System.out.println(zdt.toLocalTime());
```

You can also specify a specific Zone ID other than the system default. To see the available Zone IDs to choose from, use `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds())`

Using `ZonedDateTime` will handle daylight savings. If you simply need a static hour offset, you can convert it to an `OffsetDateTime` instead of the `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Correct. Alternatively, you can call `Instant::atZone` to produce a `ZonedDateTime`. No better, just a matter of taste.

Comment: *FYI:* Funny results for `America/New_York` time zone: `19:03:58`. Caused by time zone for New York prior to 1883 being `UTC -4:56:02`.

Answer (score -1):

[Java DateFormater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
String date = "2011-01-18 00:00:00";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"); 
Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
```

Comment: That doesn't honor the time zone.

Comment: This code uses troublesome old legacy classes that should be avoided. The Question uses their modern replacement, the java.time classes.